What does the notation $v-rB^d$ mean for a point $v$ and $B$ being unit ball?
I am reading this paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/109648.109666
Here, $B^d$ is the unit $d$ dimensional ball. $rB^d$ is the $d$ dimensional ball with radius $r$. However, in the proof of the upper bound, the author defines for a point $v \in conv(rB^d \cap \mathbb{Z}^d)$,
$$M(v) = rB^d \cap (v - rB^d)$$
The author note "Indeed, $M(v)$ is convex and centrally symmetric with respect to $v \in \mathbb{Z}^d$". I'm extremely confused. What does $v-rB^d$ mean here? What does set difference mean between a point and a ball? Is it the $rB^d$ ball translated with center $v$?

Yes. Because the ball is symmetric about the origin, $v-rB  = v + rB$.

I think the technical name for this is Minkowski sum: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition

I see, I guess this is what we get in CS for overriding $-$ to mean set difference (i.e. $V-v = V \setminus {v}$. Thank you both, the proof makes much more sense now.
